# type mismatch on debug.print range(index)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a type mismatch when trying to retrieve the value of a cell in a range, by it's index in that range.

It works for

```
Dim th As Range
Set th = ws.ListObjects("pp").HeaderRowRange
Debug.Print TypeName(th) <--- Prints "id" which it should.
```

But this one does not work

```
Dim row_ As Range
Set row_ = Range("pp").Rows(WorksheetFunction.Match(id_, Range("pp").Columns(1), 0))
Debug.Print row_(1).Value <--- Gives the mismatch error.
```

I ran TypeName for both th and row_ and both are of TypeName "Range".

The row_ is not empty, since I iterate over values. Where it prints out every value in the range.

```
For Each cell In row_.Cells
    Debug.Print cell.Value
Next cell
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Hope anyone can help.

Comment: change your `row_` variable to say, `iRow` and see if you get the error still. I don't know if VBA likes `_` as a trailing variable name.  Also, you can't print a whole row's value IIRC, what're you trying to show with `row_(1).Value`. That format look more like an array return than a single variable's value.  `row_1` should be returning a single cell range.

Comment: `Debug.Print 
 join(application.transpose(application.transpose(row_(1).Value)),",")`